# Codeigniter - How to get Available Rooms in meeting room application based on Date and Time

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In the development of the Meeting Room Booking System, I am getting an error for retrieving the available Rooms.

Database Structure is :

Table : meeting_room_bookings

Columns : id(int), meeting_room_id(int), date(date in MM/DD/YYYY format), start_time(int), end_time(int)

Below is my query, how do I get available rooms based on date and time?

```
  $this->db->select('meeting_room_id');
  $this->db->from('meeting_room_bookings');

  $this->db->where('date',$date);
  $this->db->where('start_time',$timestamp_start);
  $this->db->or_where('start_time',$timestamp_end);
  $this->db->or_where('end_time',$timestamp_start);
  $this->db->or_where('end_time',$timestamp_end);

  $where1 = "('start_time' <= $timestamp_start) AND ('end_time' >= $timestamp_start)";
  $where2 = "('start_time' <= $timestamp_end) AND ('end_time' >= $timestamp_end)";

  $this->db->or_where($where1);
  $this->db->or_where($where2);

  $data['value1'] = $this->db->get()->result();
```

Table Structure -  https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HpnK.png

Comment: paste your code here.

Comment: You expect us to __imagine__ YOUR code and __guess__ YOUR error?

Comment: add table structure of room and room booking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to get available meeting rooms you can set a tag 0 for free and 1 for busy for your meeting rooms, if someone book a meeting room  set a tag to 1 and then on meeting completion set tag to 0.